# Unlocking Security & Privacy pane in System Preferences freezes - Mojave 10.14.6

Tags: mojave, password, performance, system-settings, unlock

First off, this is a work computer so I can't do anything harsh like reinstall the OS (or upgrade to Catalina) and the hard drive is encrypted. I figured I would ask on here before bothering IS since they can take a long time to fix things. Stack exchange has always been good to me so I appreciate any tips! :)

IS had me install a bunch of OS and Microsoft Office updates last night and after a reboot this morning I need to change some settings in System Preferences (trying to troubleshoot being able to screen-share in Microsoft Teams (argh)).

When I go to unlock the "Security & Privacy" pane in System Preferences I enter my password and click on Unlock. At this point, the window freezes. I have given it over 20 minutes to see if it would unlock and nothing happens. Funny enough, the only thing unfrozen on it is the Password field, I am able to edit that as I please but the Unlock and Cancel buttons remain grayed out like so:
[image: password entry frozen]

At this point, I can't even close the window so I have to force-quit System Preferences.